# Swift - iOS Charts - Two LineChart views using Two datasets in one ViewController

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have an app where I'm getting some data from Firebase by days and I'm trying to display each day's data in a separate chart, using iOS Charts, but it crashes with an error 'fatal error: Index out of range'. Below is my code:

```
 func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }





    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    firstDayChart.data = lineChartData

}

func setChart2(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }







    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
   secondDayChart.data = lineChartData

}
```

//BUTTON

```
  @IBAction func getResults(sender: UIButton) {
    let doubleArray = BGdataOutsideDay1.map { Double($0)!}
    //  print(doubleArray)
    // var newArray:[Double] = []


    self.doublesArrayDay1 = doubleArray

    if doublesArrayDay1.count != 0 {
    let bgAvg = doubleArray.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(doubleArray.count)
    let highest = doubleArray.maxElement()
    let lowest = doubleArray.minElement()
    self.bgHighestDay1 = String(format: "%.1f", highest!)
    self.bgAvgDay1 = String(format: "%.1f", bgAvg)
    self.bgLowestDay1 = String(format: "%.1f", lowest!)
    self.firstDayHighest.text = self.bgHighestDay1! + " " + "\(self.units!)"
    self.firstDayAvg.text = self.bgAvgDay1! + " " + "\(self.units!)"
    self.firstDayLowest.text = self.bgLowestDay1! + " " + "\(self.units!)"
    } else {
        self.firstDayHighest.text = "0" + " " + "\(self.units!)"
        self.firstDayAvg.text = "0" + " " + "\(self.units!)"
        self.firstDayLowest.text = "0" + " " + "\(self.units!)"

    }
    let doubleArray2 = BGdataOutsideDay2.map { Double($0)!}
    //  print(doubleArray)
    // var newArray:[Double] = []


    self.doublesArrayDay2 = doubleArray

    if doublesArrayDay2.count != 0 {
        let bgAvg2 = doubleArray2.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(doubleArray.count)
        let highest2 = doubleArray2.maxElement()
        let lowest2 = doubleArray2.minElement()
        self.bgHighestDay2 = String(format: "%.1f", highest2!)
        self.bgAvgDay2 = String(format: "%.1f", bgAvg2)
        self.bgLowestDay2 = String(format: "%.1f", lowest2!)
        self.secondDayHighest.text = self.bgHighestDay2! + " " + "\(self.units!)"
        self.secondDayAvg.text = self.bgAvgDay2! + " " + "\(self.units!)"
        self.secondDayLowest.text = self.bgLowestDay2! + " " + "\(self.units!)"
    } else {
        self.secondDayHighest.text = "0" + " " + "\(self.units!)"
        self.secondDayAvg.text = "0" + " " + "\(self.units!)"
        self.secondDayLowest.text = "0" + " " + "\(self.units!)"
         setChart(DateOutSideDay1, values: doublesArrayDay1)
    setChart(DateOutSideDay2, values: doublesArrayDay2)

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It seems like the `values` array has less items than the `dataPoints` array. This would explain the error you're getting.

Comment: Yes, I know the reason, but I would like to make it work :)

Comment: did you check which array is causing this issue?

Comment: let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
it crashes here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i think it's weird that you have a set of data points and another set of values, but they aren't the same size? Imo those sets should be the same size since the values represent the data points.

Anywho..

You can fix this issue by replacing `let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)` with `let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: i < values.count ? values[i] : 0, xIndex: i)`

You can define a default value to be used when there's no value available at that index in the `values` array, I set it to `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)